# Is there a good way to stream video FROM Android to an RTSP server?

Tags: java, android, rtsp

I have searched around and haven't really found anything. I would like to send the video from the built in camera to my RTSP server via a stream. When looking for examples, I saw that it might be possible for MediaPlayer to have its setDataSource() method to just include the location of the stream on the server. I tried to emulate that with:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("rtsp://x.x.x.x/mystream2.mpg");
mediaRecorder.prepare();
mediaRecorder.start();
```

I am attempting to use LIVE555 to simulate a server in case that might be any reason for the hold up. However, the problem is probably a lock of understanding of how things work on my part. Any insight as to things I could try would be highly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

(Also, the x's are replaced with numbers, I just don't know why adding the IPs I'm using would be terribly helpful)

If there's anything I can add to help, let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: When I run this currently, I get a FileNotFoundException (which makes sense I think because I haven't created a file on my server), but I was hoping it would take care of that. Since it didn't I tried making a new File at that location using:
    (new File("rtsp://x.x.x.x/mystream2.mpg")).createNewFile();
and that threw an IOException. I don't know if this helps any, but I thought I would share just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up just using a standard protocol smashing JPEG after JPEG and loading those and it more-or-less simulates real time. We could still use a better solution, but this worked for now. If anybody wants to see some code, leave a comment. If anybody has a better solution, post it and I will switch the answer over.

Comment: I think we always welcome some spiffy code! :o) Very interesting approach to say the least although I cannot provide anything better.

Comment: Alright, I think I can post it. Any particular way to include it? in the question or the answer?

Comment: You should include your code in your answer. You can edit your own answer as many times as you like.

Comment: This link describe it in detail ..   http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/

Answer (score 4):

You should look into this --> https://github.com/spex66/RTSP-Camera-for-Android

I took their code and added ANNOUNCE and RECORD methods to the rtsp client.

And i successfully got streaming to work from android phone to darwin server.

Comment: Can you please provide us the code to me..I need this code urgently.