# How to play live streaming in android application?

Tags: java, android

I want to make application for cricket live streaming.
I want to know following things :

1. From where I can found the links to play cricket streaming ?
2. Which type of links are these ?
3. Is there any player to play this type of videos ?

Currently, I have implemented web page but I am looking for other alternative.

Below is my code :

```
    link1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.link1);
    link2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.link2);
    link3 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.link3);
    link4 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.link4);
    link5 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.link5);
    link6 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.link6);
    link7 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.link7);
    link1.setOnClickListener(this);
    link2.setOnClickListener(this);
    link3.setOnClickListener(this);
    link4.setOnClickListener(this);
    link5.setOnClickListener(this);
    link6.setOnClickListener(this);
    link7.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.link1:
         linkFunction("http://changevssame.blogspot.com/2014/03/willow-cricket-hd-live-streaming.html");

        break;
    case R.id.link2:
        linkFunction("http://changevssame.blogspot.com/2014/03/foxsports-live-streaming.html");
        break;
    case R.id.link3:
        linkFunction("http://changevssame.blogspot.com/2014/03/sky-sports-live-streaming.html");
        break;
    case R.id.link4:
        linkFunction("http://changevssame.blogspot.com/2014/03/ten-sports-live-streaming.html");
        break;
    case R.id.link5:
        linkFunction("http://changevssame.blogspot.com/2014/03/star-cricket.html");
        break;
    case R.id.link6:
        linkFunction("http://changevssame.blogspot.com/2014/03/icc-t20-world-cup-2014-live-streaming.html");
        break;
    case R.id.link7:
        linkFunction("http://changevssame.blogspot.com/2014/03/ptv-sports.html");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You can use VideoView and set this urls into videoview.

Answer (score 19):

I will try to answer your questions but there are many fundamentals you've got to learn in order to build up a successful Streaming Application.

> ```
> 1. From where I can found the links to play cricket streaming ?
> ```

No idea, but this is not a SO standard question anyway.

> ```
> 2. Which type of links are these ?
> ```

IF you mean live streaming links, there are many types but mostly they are either HLS or RTSP.
HLS links are simple HTTP links that often end with a ".m3u8" postfix. (e.g "http://somewebsite.com/streams/hls_stream_video.m3u8")

RTSP links on the other hand, have a format like this: "rtsp://somewebsite.com/streams/an_rtsp_stream.mp4"

> ```
> 3. Is there any player to play this type of videos ?
> ```

Absolutely. You can do so by any means. 
I'm not exactly sure by "a player" whether you mean Android API player or third-party player applications. So I'll cover both cases for you and future passengers.

**I) Android API:** You can do so with the help of a `MediaController`, a `MediaPlayer` and a `SurafceView`. The latter two are also available in a unit entity known as `VideoView`.
There is a code in the answer below, you can use that. But Be aware of two key points:

I-a) Using `MediaPlayer` is harder to implement but gives you more detailed control compared to `VideoView`.

I-b) If you use some code similar to the below answer **Never** call prepare() for network streams. Always **prepareAsync()**. And **Always** call **setAudioStreamType()** before prepareAsync. Otherwise you will face transient *sync* issues between  Audio and Video when seeking on the progressbar.

**II) Player Application:** I have done streaming with MXPlayer and it works great.

There are some considerations to take before starting:

### What protocol to choose?

Assuming you are targeting Android, I can advice you to narrow your choices down to HLS and RTSP.
You need to study them well before making a decision. But to give you a hint. HLS is preferred when functioning on lower Bandwidths.

There are many other topics like whether to choose **UDP/TCP**, **IP-Multicast/Broadcast** and so on...

### Want to delve into coding and learn Video Streaming programmatically?

Go and visit [this tutorial](http://androidcodingworld.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-video-streaming-example.html). This is the most complete zero-to-hero guide in my opinion.

---

Since SO lacks a thorough post on **Video Streaming**, maybe I will extend my answer on demand.

Comment: This should be a comment and not answer.

Comment: @Siddhath Vys: Duely noted. How about this? ;)

Comment: There you go.. ;) +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link :

[Android Video Streaming](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/)

Below code works for me :

```
public static void getVideoFromHttp(String urlPath) {

try {
// Start the MediaController
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(mContext);
mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoview);
// Get the URL from String VideoURL
Uri mVideo = Uri.parse(urlPath);
mVideoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
mVideoview.setVideoURI(mVideo);

} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();

}

mVideoview.requestFocus();
mVideoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
// Close the progress bar and play the video
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
mVideoview.start();

}
});

mVideoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

}
});

}
```

Comment: urlPath is your link. Example : http://changevssame.blogspot.com/2014/03/willow-cricket-hd-live-streaming.html

Comment: i use url which you mention but it gives "Can't play this video"

Comment: This is just an example.You can try other links.And by the way, this is the link which you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: its work
but my question is on live streaming 
i want to play live channel streaming in which i know the iframe link of that channel
how can i play that video in full screen
for example
this is a iframe link how can i play this channel live streaming 

<IFRAME FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=600 HEIGHT=420 SRC="http://www.streamer247.com/star4.php"></IFRAME>

Comment: Please check the answer given by "Campiador" regarding formats supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void playLive(String path){

   try {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
      }
}
```

Comment: i use url which you mention but it gives "Can't play this video"

Comment: i want to play live channel streaming in which i know the iframe link of that channel how can i play that video in full screen for example this is a iframe link how can i play this channel live streaming <IFRAME FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=600 HEIGHT=420 SRC="streamer247.com/star4.php"></IFRAME>