# android live streaming app using embed code

Tags: java, android, web, video-streaming

Can anyone please guide me on how to resize video(fit to screen and full screen) in web view.
I am trying to stream from embed link of channels in android app 
here is code snippet

```
String playVideo= "<html><body><iframe type=\"text/html\" width=\"350\" height=\"235\"src=\"http:www.skyembed.com/skysports1.php\" frameborder=\"0\"></body></html>";

webView.loadData(playVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean resizing the `WebView` or `iframe` to full screen, you can use this :

in layout xml

```
<WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/webView"
></WebView>
```

in java source :

```
      WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.ww);

     // **** use width="100%" and height="100%" to fill the webview by iFrame ******
     String playVideo= "<html><body><iframe type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"src=\"http:www.skyembed.com/skysports1.php\" frameborder=\"0\"></body></html>";

     webView.loadData(playVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

but if you mean resizing the src elements in `http:www.skyembed.com/skysports1.php` . it is not possible. this has to done from server side .by adding a javaScript like this :

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myFrame");
   if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
       }
```

finallay if you need to paly a streamed video , best way is using `MediaPlayer`.
[How to play live streaming in android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344344/how-to-play-live-streaming-in-android-application)

Comment: thanx ,got that already
after a lot of search,since there wasnt any direct answer like this