# How to send Video to Webservice api using Socket.IO in android

Tags: java, android, socket.io

I am completely new to this socket.io concept. My requirement is to send the frame or a video to Webservice Api using Socket.IO in android. Any one pls advice me where to start or any example projects available.

I tried two projects(Java projects) from github but there are errors. Can u please suggest me any android projects to start with!

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Hey what u want exactly....I mean you are developing vedio chating app and you want to share user current video frame to other user Am i right, ya something else.

Comment: I this is what you are looking for [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245537/transfer-real-time-video-stream-to-server-using-android)

Comment: Hi, i was asked just to send a video frame to server using Socket.io @SO Answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing vedio chatting App and you want to share user current video frame to other user.

[Example link](https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial)